# I keep getting hit with TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python

I keep getting hit with the same error over and over again and I cant seem to understand why.  This is the json file

```
{
    "id": 1233445,
    "type": "message",
    "date": "2022-09-09T18:33:54",
    "date_unixtime": "1662229634",
    "from": "Username",
    "from_id": "user11111",
    "text": "Helloooo",
    "text_entities": [{
        "type": "plain",
        "text": "Helloooo"
    }]
```

This is the code below

```
#import
import json
# Open the input file
with open(r"C:\Users\kooki\OneDrive\Documents\result.json", 'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
# Extract the relevant information from each message
for message in data:
    message_dict = {}
    message_dict['id'] = message['id']
    message_dict['type'] = message['type']
    message_dict['date'] = message['date']
    message_dict['from'] = message['from']
    message_dict['text'] = message['text']
    messages.append(message_dict)
```

Comment: `message` here is actually a key / string; i.e. the error is correct

Comment: THe JSOn data is incorrect. It starts with a `{` and ends with a `]`. And if you add a `}` as the last character the error message shoukld be clear. Please add a `print(message)` in your loop, so that you can see what you are working with.

Comment: The JSON file only contains one message, not a list of messages.

Comment: @Matthias The `]` matches `"text_entities": [`.

Comment: That's probably a copying error, since they're not getting an error from `json.load()`

Comment: Get rid of the loop. Just do `messages.append(data)`

Comment: Adding a `[` as the first character and `}]` as the last characters will make it a list of messages.

Comment: The code snippet seems to be uncomplete (e.g. messages is not declared). Also: you are using backslashes for the path, however these need to be escaped using an other backslash (C:\\Users\\kooki\\OneDrive\\Documents\\result.json)

Comment: @fatorice You missed the fact that the path is defined as a raw string.

Comment: `for message in data:` this is iterating over the keys of the `data` dictionary. So, on each iteration, `message` will be just a string, like "id", "type", "date"... you are trying to do `message['id']`, which resolves to `"id"['id']`, which gives the error.

Comment: `for message in data:` here message is a key in the dictionary data. Essentially `data` is already `message_dict` and you don't need the for loop.

Answer (score 3):

The error says that instead of the expected `string[0]` with an integer as its index, it gets `string['string']` and gets confused.

We can see why that happened – if you want to directly access `data['id']`, there's no need to loop through it. In your code `message` is a string, hence why `message['id']` threw that error.

```py
#import
import json

messages = [] # Added this because "messages" hasn't been defined yet, at least in the snippet

# Open the input file
with open(r"C:\Users\kooki\OneDrive\Documents\result.json", 'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# Extract the relevant information from each message
message_dict = {}
message_dict['id'] = data['id']
message_dict['type'] = data['type']
message_dict['date'] = data['date']
message_dict['from'] = data['from']
message_dict['text'] = data['text']
messages.append(message_dict)
```

It looks like the code can be refined further without declaring `message_dict` at all (because it's the exact same as `data`), but hope it works :)

Alternatively, since they new `message_dict` used the same keys as `data` and we are essentially replicating part of `data` you might also look at:

```py
# Extract the relevant information from each message
messages.append({
    key: data[key]
    for key in data
    if key in ['id', 'type', 'date', 'from', 'text']
})
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Semantics Side :
   Mainly the problem comes from that the JSON file you have represents just a "single message info" not multiple messages that you can iterate on.
   Your code will work in case JSON file have array of messages ( message objects ) like,

   ```
    [{
      "id": 1233445,
      "type": "message",
      "date": "2022-09-09T18:33:54",
      "date_unixtime": "1662229634",
      "from": "Username",
      "from_id": "user11111",
      "text": "Helloooo",
      "text_entities": [{
          "type": "plain",
          "text": "Helloooo"
      }]
   },
   {
      "id": 1233445,
      "type": "message",
      "date": "2022-09-09T18:33:54",
      "date_unixtime": "1662229634",
      "from": "Username",
      "from_id": "user11111",
      "text": "Helloooo",
      "text_entities": [{
          "type": "plain",
          "text": "Helloooo"
      }]
   }]
   ```

but in case that your JSON will have info for just one message so the problem is Logical not semantics one.

2. Logical Side :
   The error comes from trying to iterate on the "data" , dict object ( python dictionary ), as when you do the `for message in data :` this iterates on list of keys of this dict , so on each iteration 'message' variable will have a key ( in this case all keys are strings ) so the problem emerges from here ' message['id'] ', trying to access a string chars using another string which is not appropriate ( index must be integer value).

so we can use the following code to do the job ,

```
import json
with open(r"C:\Users\kooki\OneDrive\Documents\result.json", 'r',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

messages = []
needed_params = ['id','type','date','from','text']

message_dict = {}
for parameter in needed_params :
    message_dict[parameter] = data[parameter]
messages.append(message_dict)
```